# "kvm disabled by bios" when installing in a Packard Bell

Tags: bios, kvm-virtualization

Packard Bell computers seem to have an issue installing Ubuntu. To get it to actually load the installation disk I had to go into the bios settings and boot settings and change type to legacy and turn off secure boot.

I have a te69kb with amda4 5000.

Once I got it loading I clicked install, but it did not recognize any partitions. I installed anyway and wiped the disk. Once it was done I restarted it and once it got past the bios I got an error. It said: kvm disabled by bios. It then gives me a terminal and prompts me to log in. When I do I type startx and that fails and gives me a final error of no windows.

Comment: Had the same problem. The kvm error was unrelated to the graphics issue. I tried ubuntu 14.04 and graphics worked for me. However the kvm error still happens. The bios has no option I can find for virtualisation. Since I also accidentally wiped windows I cannot install the bios update (it comes as a windows executable)

Answer (score 1):

The "kvm disabled by bios" error is a know error and according to [this page](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/FAQ#.22KVM%3a_disabled_by_BIOS.22_error) you should be able to fix your problem by enabling it in the bios

> "KVM: disabled by BIOS" error
>   Check if there is an option to enable it in the BIOS. If not, look for a more recent BIOS on the vendor's web site.
>
> Note:
>
> On some hardware (e-g HP nx6320), you need to power-off/power-on the
>   machine after enabling virtualization in the BIOS.
>
> Enabling some BIOS
>   features may break VT support on some hardware (e-g Enabling Intel AMT
>   on a Thinkpad T500 will prevent kvm-intel from loading with "disabled
>   by bios")
>
> On some Dell hardware, you also need to disable "Trusted
>   Execution", otherwise VT will not be enabled.

if that doesn't work try re-installing you linux (comment if that does not work either)